# installing texinfo on redhat centos 7 ppc64

Tags: perl, centos, redhat, rpm, texinfo

I am new to RedHat and would like some help to install `R-devel`.

I tried to install it using the following command:

```
yum install R-devel
```

but leads to the first error below...

I am on CentOS 7 with a ppc64 architecture...

I have got to the point of needing to install `texinfo-tex`, `lapack-devel` and `blas-devel`. Please see below:

```
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.1.3-1.el7.ppc64 (epel)
            Requires: texinfo-tex
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.1.3-1.el7.ppc64 (epel)
           Requires: lapack-devel
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.1.3-1.el7.ppc64 (epel)
           Requires: blas-devel >= 3.0
```

`yum install texinfo-tex` does not seem to work as it says `No package texinfo-tex available`.

So I downloaded the .rpm and used the following command...to try and install it

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh texinfo-5.2-7.fc22.ppc64.rpm'
```

with which i get the following error

```
warning: texinfo-5.2-7.fc22.ppc64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID xxxxxx:NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(Unicode::EastAsianWidth) is needed by texinfo-5.2-7.fc22.ppc64
```

So i try and install the dependency `perl(Unicode::EastAsianWidth)`

again trying to download and try and install it...

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh perl-Unicode-EastAsianWidth-1.33-4.fc22.noarch.rpm'

warning: perl-Unicode-EastAsianWidth-1.33-4.fc22.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID xxxxx: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
         perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.20.0) is needed by perl-Unicode-EastAsianWidth-1.33-4.fc22.noarch
```

so i tried to also install `perl` using the following:

```
 su -c 'rpm -Uvh perl-5.20.1-314.fc22.ppc64.rpm'
```

but got even more dependecy checks....i feel like this probably isn't right...am i missing something...

I have also installed `perlbrew` to check my perl versions this is my result

```
perlbrew available
#  perl-5.21.10   
  perl-5.20.2
  perl-5.18.4
  perl-5.16.3
  perl-5.14.4
  perl-5.12.5
  perl-5.10.1
  perl-5.8.9
  perl-5.6.2
  perl5.005_04
  perl5.004_05
  perl5.003_07
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Use yum to resolve dependancies automatically and note that a perl installed with `perlbrew` is completely independent from anything that you installed via RPM.

Comment: Strange...I'm on CentOS 7 and I see `texinfo-tex` in the base yum repository.

Comment: how would you be able to do it using the .rpm?

Comment: Make sure that your network adapter is turned on also.   Often network manager will have interfaces turned off at boot time, and yum can't download anything from the repository as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command as the root user:

```
yum localinstall texinfo-5.2-7.fc22.ppc64.rpm
```

Comment: I get a very similar error to before: --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: texinfo-5.2-7.fc22.ppc64 (/texinfo-5.2-7.fc22.ppc64)
           Requires: perl(Unicode::EastAsianWidth)
           Available: texinfo-5.1-4.el7.ppc64 (Local)
               perl(Unicode::EastAsianWidth) = 1.30
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: Try adding --skip-broken to the end of the command.  That's what the error message is suggestin.